# Why does a .NET Core app need C# AND VB assemblies?

Tags: .net-core

I noticed that among the dependencies for a .NET Core application, there are `Microsoft.CSharp` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, with pretty much the same dependencies:

[image]

I'd like to better understand:

1. Why (what seem like) language-specific DLLs are needed in the first place;
2. Why both DLLs are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why (what seem like) language-specific DLLs are needed in the first place;

They exist to support language-specific functionality. In the case of C#, this is primarily for `dynamic`. In the case of VB, this is mostly for VB-specific members, like `AscW` or `vbCrLf` (which can be used from C# too) and also some types used by the VB compiler.

> Why both DLLs are needed.

Because, at least in theory, the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package, which includes both the C# and the VB package, is language neutral. Though in practice, VB is not currently supported on .Net Core. And F# (which is supported) has its own package, which is not included by default.